# define a relation $R$ on $S$?

Tags: relations

Let S be the set of humans.

1) Define a relation $R$ on $S$ that is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive but not antisymmetric

2) Define a relation $R$ on $S$ that is symmetric and antisymmetric

Can someone help me understand how to start this? Would we have to create a list of pairs to show the relation?

Comment: Which set is S?

Comment: What is S defined to be?

Comment: Sorry i just found it

Comment: So let $S$ be your favorite (preferably finite) set. Just start by making a few ordered pairs of elements of $S$ until you have what you want.

Comment: What would the ordered pair look like (1,1) , (2,2) and so on?

Comment: If your set contains $1$ and $2$, then yes. Just remember what each statement says: Reflexive- everything relates to itself. Symmetric- $x$ relates to $y$ means $y$ relates to $x$. Transitive- $x$ relates to $y$ relates to $z$ means $x$ relates to $z$. Antisymmetric- if $x$ relates to $y$ and vice versa, then $x=y$.

Comment: so if i was to prove that R on S is reflexive, symmetric  , and transitive, it would be like (1,1) (1,2) (2,1) ,(2,2)   but not anti symmetric i don't get

Comment: First, you should define $S$, say $S=\{1,2\}$. The relation you defined is not antisymmetric because you have two different elements $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ relates to $y$ and $y$ relates to $x$.

Comment: Non-symmetric and anti-symmetric are not the same thing! Non-symmetric means $\exists x,y\;(x R y\land \neg (y R x)).$ Anti-symmetric means $\forall x,y\;(x R y\implies \neg (y R x)).$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to give a hint to number 1 without giving it away.  I'd suggest just trying natural language relationships.  Example a R b if b is the mother of a, but is it reflexive?  Is a R a? Is a always the mother of a? Of course not.  How about if a R b if a and b have the same parents.  Is it reflexive? Does a have the same parents as him/herself.  Yes,  Symmetric, if a has the same parents as b does b have the same parents as a? Yes.  Transitive?  If a and b have the same parents and b and c have the same parents, do a and c have the same parents?

As for 2).  Note .  Symmetric means whenever a R b then *always* b R a.  But anti-symmetric says, whenever a R b and b Ra then *always* a = b.  So if a relation is *both* symmetric and anti-symetric then a R b => b R a = > b = a.  So *always* if a R b then a = b.  So no two different elements can be related and only same elements can be related.  But a same element doesn't have to be related to itself.

Here are three examples:  everybody is related to themselves and no-one else.  No body is related to anybody not even themselves.  Sam Spade, Barrack Obama, and Kim Kardashian are all related to themselves; nobody else is related to anybody else or to themselves.

Now that I've given you some answers, you need to come up with some completely different answers.

Answer (score 0):

1) Observe that $R$ is demanded to be an equivalence relation. That means that it induces a partition on $S$. Working in opposite direction you can also start with some partition on humans (lots of choices) and then define $R$ by stating that $aRb$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ belong to the same component of the partition. Then automatically $R$ is an equivalence relation.

2) If $R$ is symmetric and antisymmetric then $aRb$ leads firstly to $bRa$ (by symmetry)  and leads secondly to $a=b$ (by antisymmetry).

So it is necessary that $$R\subseteq\Delta:=\{\langle a,a\rangle\mid a\in S\}$$ Conversely  $R\subseteq\Delta$ is also a sufficient condition for $R$ to be symmetric and antisymmetric.